# Python Line Chart with matplotlib.pyplot not displayed correctly - I get a straight diagonal line

Tags: python, python-3.x, matplotlib

I have the following code:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import csv

with open('results simulation.csv', newline='') as f:
    reader = csv.reader(f)
    data = list(reader)

Generation = data[0]
Points = data[1]

plt.plot(Generation, Points)
plt.title('Points for every Generation')
plt.xlabel('Generation')
plt.ylabel('Points')
plt.show()
```

And this is the chart that I get:[image]

As you can I get a straight line, even though the values are different

Any ideas?

Comment: Your data are strings, not ints or floats.

Comment: You might want to migrate to numpy or Pandas when reading CSVs, they make life easier. You might also have sliced your table wrong, try plotting with points instead of full line. That always helps debugging.

Comment: @BigBen Thank you so much! Almost forgot about this!